# Edit file not in pull request commit

Tags: git, github

I am reviewing a PR that has failed to build but see the issue is with a file that is not in the 'files changed' column. Does anyone know how would I go about changing that specific file?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would need to checkout the feature branch corresponding to this pull request, edit the file, then commit and push.  As to whether you *should* do this depends on several things.  That the build is failing due to some file not in the change set is a smell, because it raises the question of whether the owner of this PR even had the build working when it pushed.  You may want to speak to the owner of the PR.